# When will MSAL.JS be released (General Availability Release)?

Tags: javascript, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, adal.js

Currently the documentation for Microsoft Authentication Library Preview for JavaScript (MSAL.js) - https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js states the following:

*When we provide the General Availability release we will require you to update to the General Availability version within six months, as applications written using a preview version of library may no longer work.*

Are there any upcoming features that are slated to be released with the GA build?  Do we have an available Roadmap of what to expect for the GA build?  And, is an approximate GA release date available?

This information would be helpful in determining the usage of this library for our upcoming and future Production Application builds.

Comment: Have you posted this as an issue on the GitHub repo?

Comment: Thanks!  I just did.  https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/285